# VBA openweathermap XML retrieval

Tags: xml, vba, excel, openweathermap

I have a spreadsheet that has city,state in col A. I would like to get precip type/value for 3 days from current day into column B. I started working with openweathermap API and I found that my lack of experience with XML is killing me. Below is how I started and I haven't been able to get much further. Any attempt I've made to work with the nodes and elements have not been working out. Any help would be appreciated.

here is a link to a sample XML
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Boston+MA&mode=xml&units=metric&cnt=7?

```vb
Option Explicit

Function CityForecast(City As String) As String
Dim StartingURL As String
Dim SecondaryURL As String
Dim FinalURL As String
Dim CorrectedCity As String
Dim objXML As Object
Dim objDOM As MSXML2.DOMDocument60

CorrectedCity = Replace(City, " ", "+")
CorrectedCity = Replace(City, ",", "+")

StartingURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q="
SecondaryURL = "&mode=xml&units=metric&cnt=7"
FinalURL = StartingURL + CorrectedCity + SecondaryURL
Debug.Print FinalURL

Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Set objDOM = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

With objXML
    .Open "GET", FinalURL, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-URLEncoded"
    .send
    objDOM.LoadXML .responseText
End With


End Function

Function CorrectedDate(WxDate As String) As String
Dim yr As Integer
Dim dy As Integer
Dim mnth As Integer

yr = Left(WxDate, 4)
mnth = Right(Left(WxDate, 7), 2)
dy = Right(WxDate, 2)

CorrectedDate = mnth & "/" & dy & "/" & yr
End Function
```

Comment: should be pretty easy using xpath , I think... give me a few to test it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. I uysed DOMDocument instead of DOMDocument60 which was raising an error for me. You may not need to change that variable, but I did.

This function is also modified to accept a variable forecast, `daysOut`. So if you want the forecast for the third day *from today* (including today), do:

`=CityForecast("Boston, MA", 3)`

Here is the code:

```vb
Option Explicit

    Function CityForecast(City As String, daysOut As Integer) As String
    Dim StartingURL As String
    Dim SecondaryURL As String
    Dim FinalURL As String
    Dim CorrectedCity As String
    Dim objXML As Object
    Dim objDOM As MSXML2.DOMDocument  '### Changed
    'new variables I added:
    Dim precip As IXMLDOMNode


    CorrectedCity = Replace(City, " ", "+")
    CorrectedCity = Replace(City, ",", "+")

    StartingURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q="
    SecondaryURL = "&mode=xml&units=metric&cnt=7"
    FinalURL = StartingURL + CorrectedCity + SecondaryURL
    Debug.Print FinalURL

    Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set objDOM = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")   '### Changed

    With objXML
        .Open "GET", FinalURL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-URLEncoded"
        .send
        objDOM.LoadXML .responseText
    End With

    'Use xpath to get the appropriate precipitation detail
    Set precip = objDOM.SelectSingleNode("/weatherdata/forecast/time[" & daysOut & "]/precipitation")


    If precip Is Nothing Then 
    ' in the event that the node doesn't exist
        CityForecast = "n/a" 
    Else
    ' otherwise, return the forecast attribute (0):
        If precip.Attributes.Length = 0 then
            CityForecast = 0
        Else
            CityForecast = precip.Attributes(0).nodeTypedValue
        End IF
    End If

    Set objXML = Nothing
    Set objDOM = Nothing

    End Function
```

Comment: That is awesome and I made some alterations to also get the precip type. One thing I have noticed is that sometimes it does not work but when I open up the XML in a web browser then it works...Is there a way around this where it works always?

Comment: the functions output #VALUE!. It is hit or miss it seems. I have the same issue with Google maps API. But when I open IE and look at the XML then suddenly the functions in Excel work.

Comment: You're going to need some additional debugging then. All functions will return that error whenever *any* error is encountered within the execution of the function. With XML parsing, there is quite a lot that could go wrong... I'll make a small revision which might help.